# Draw Image of Userinterface onto Glasspane

Tags: java, swing, paint, glasspane

I'm trying to draw a modified version of my GUI onto the Glasspane. My idea is to have a panel where I override the paint function, but when I trysomething like

```
glass = frame.getGlasspane();
glass.draw(g);
```

I get a Nullpointer Exception, even though I initialized the glasspane with frame.setGlasspane(new JPanel());

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

please read [How to Use Root Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) follows example, example about [paint(Graphics g)](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Paintonglasspane.htm) or [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GlassPane.htm)